# sort the output flat file schema in Biztalk based on one node

Tags: xml, csv, xslt-1.0, biztalk, flat-file

I have  flat file schema as output after doing a complex mapping.

Now I want to sort the data of flat file schema based on **values of one node** as I am saving this schema as csv in the end. (as per my requirement)

So when I open my csv, the data must be sorted alphabetically based on one node.

Is there a way to do it.

I can achieve it while populating data to the schema, Just wondering is there a way to sort the schema later too.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is using XSLT, here is a little example i made for you, as you see all you have to do is to add  in your for each statement to for example sort by title, for more information go here http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_sort.asp

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<catalog xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
    <foo:cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <bar:year>1985</bar:year>
    </foo:cd>
    <foo:cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <bar:year>1988</bar:year>
    </foo:cd>
    <foo:cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>RCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <bar:year>1982</bar:year>
    </foo:cd>
</catalog>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Year</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/foo:cd">
             <xsl:sort select="title"/>
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="country"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="company"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="bar:year"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not built in.  You'd have to remap it (using Custom XSLT) or load it into an XDocument and save it over the original message after using some kind of LINQ calls to sort it.